# How to set the LAN ip adress to automatic through command prompt?

Tags: cmd, ip

I am trying to make a small program for quickly setting up a local 'network'. To do this I set my LAN ip adress from automatic to static in cmd.exe:

```
C:> netsh interface ip set address name=”Ethernet” static 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
```

My question is: how does one reverse this?

I've already tried things like:

```
C:> netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" automatic/auto and stuff like that.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is better suited for Stack Exchange's Network Engineering site: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry i'm not very familiar with forums like this (yet) ;)

Comment: No worries.  Good luck to you.

Comment: `netsh interface ip set address /?` says DHCP.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Would prefer SuperUser, cause it's not a network related question but a windows related one.